# Python SSH using Popen

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, popen

How do I `ssh` using `Popen` by answering yes by default when faced with this?

```
The authenticity of host '`XXXXX`' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:LA2RqbdzD8Uxgi36KWOM12giS9T+ceOQYhYjVKReMks.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

this is what I'm trying

```
for IP in ['10.32.253.250']:
    remoteCall = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "co_user@"+IP, "sudo svstat /etc/sv/nagios_CheckDisk_Alertz_daemon",], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE);
    Response, err = remoteCall.communicate()
    if(re.search("authenticity of host", Response)):
        stdin.write('yes')
    print IP + "  " +Response
```

Comment: You should use `pexpect` or a dedicated ssh client such as `paramiko`.

Comment: No it's not possible to use external modules like paramiko

Comment: `No it's not possible to use ...` - why not?

Comment: I"ll try this in my local. But I was thinking if I have to run this script in external boxes where I may not have rights to install external modules.
And on a different note,  can i accept more than one answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the man page:

> StrictHostKeyChecking
>
> If this flag is set to “yes”, ssh(1) will never automatically add host
>   keys to the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file, and refuses to connect to hosts
>   whose host key has changed. This provides maximum protection against
>   trojan horse attacks, though it can be annoying when the
>   /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts file is poorly maintained or when connections
>   to new hosts are frequently made. This option forces the user to
>   manually add all new hosts. If this flag is set to “no”, ssh will
>   automatically add new host keys to the user known hosts files. If this
>   flag is set to “ask”, new host keys will be added to the user known
>   host files only after the user has confirmed that is what they really
>   want to do, and ssh will

You can set StrictHostKeyChecking to "no" if you want ssh/scp to automatically accept new keys without prompting. On the command line:

```
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ...
```

You can also enable batch mode:

```
BatchMode
```

> If set to “yes”, passphrase/password querying will be disabled. This
>   option is useful in scripts and other batch jobs where no user is
>   present to supply the password. The argument must be “yes” or “no”.
>   The default is “no”. With BatchMode=yes, ssh/scp will fail instead of
>   prompting (which is often an improvement for scripts).

Comment: That's workaround, removing the security that the host keys provide.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how subprocess do it, next is another way, maybe helpful to you. FYI.

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("192.168.1.6", 22, "username", "password")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls') // your command here
content = stdout.readlines()
print content
ssh.close()
```